# customization in Action Panel and setting panel

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I need to customize top default bar with my UI.
Check image 1( its default )[image]

I am working directly on master S4 (sharepoint 2010)
how can I do the following, 
1. switching the language ( language pack is already installed, but not showing in this image 1)
2. in 'system Account' dropdown, only show 'mysettings, sign as different user, signout'
3. use the profile image?

[image]
I know there is no click and done thing, I really appreciate for the reference of article or way to accomplish these.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open the SharePoint site, then click "Site Actions" menu > "Site Settings".

[image]

Click "Language Settings" under "Site Administration".

[image]

Check the alternate and targeted language(s) then click OK.
[image]

use the MUI to change the default language "English" into alternate checked language "Arabic" via clicking on the the context menu of welcome user menu and select "Select Display Language" then "Arabic".

[image]

Comment: great, but I need outside of the dropdown menu, check image2

Comment: for that you will need to create a custom web part what i did in my case. 2 button controls and setting the actions in the controls for redirections.